# Azure Functions - v2 support and v1 lifetime

Tags: azure, azure-functions

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101379/azure-function-v2-net-framework) - Azure functions v2 only supports .Net Core

We currently have Azure Functions v1 in production using .NET 4.6.1 which rely on 3rd party dlls which we do not have a .NET Core version yet. It could be 1-2 years before we get the 3rd party dlls to .NET Core, if ever. So some key questions I think everyone will want to know about upgrades are:

Q1 - Are there any plans to have Azure Functions v2 support the regular .NET Framework in the future to make upgrading our production system possible? If so are there any rough dates of when this might be available?

Q2 - If not then how long can we expect Microsoft to support Azure Functions v1? Is there an official mainstream & extended support schedule of dates like other Microsoft products announcing when you are going to turn off Azure Functions v1 ?

The killer issue here being if Microsoft turn off Azure Functions v1 without supporting .NET Framework on Azure Functions v2 this will cause significant problems for our production system in the future and we will need to stop migrating our code base to Azure Functions due to the lack of support.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic here, as you're asking for specific roadmap/support/sunset plans for an Azure service. You'll need to ask this directly to the support team (e.g. msdn forum, twitter, uservoice).

Comment: okay thanks - ill ask there.

Comment: You'll have a good possibility to ask your questions here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPBuvzlIpf0

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Microsoft has not announced any plans to support the Azure Functions v2 runtime with .NET Framework. They rewrote it with .NET Core specifically to fully support the latest version of .NET, while also being cross-platform. MS has a big cross-platform push in their tools and cloud support at the moment.

Q2: I haven't seen any mention as to how long the Azure Functions v1 Runtime will be supported. I would expect it to be mentioned when the v2 Runtime becomes Generally Available (GA). They haven't stated when the v2 Runtime will be GA, but with the Microsoft //Build 2018 conference coming up next week (as I write this) we may find out more then.

Overall, I would recommend waiting to see what MS announces at //Build next week, and then contact the Azure Support team directly regarding SLA's and long term support guarantees.